# PMSM motor with large time constant

Tags: pmsm

I found out, that PMSM motor with large electrical time constant (Tau = L/R) are more difficult to control with FOC. What is the reason? From my experience in control system theory, a system with slow dynamics is more easy to control.

What can I do to increase the performance for large time constant PMSM motors? Higher Voltage? Or are there better methods?

Comment: can you provide a source?

Comment: A system that reacts immediately, but slowly is easier to control but a system with a lag between input and output is a pain the ass. Just in general.

Comment: Not difficult to control *if* the control loop is correctly tuned (as oppose to Ziegler–Nichols...). More often of not people pick a motor that isn't appropriate for their use case and then try to get it working. Large time constant (be it mech or elec) imposes bandwidth considerations on the controller to mitigate overshooting